# Drywall and tile to top of shower

Tags: drywall, shower, tile

Looking for some tips on how best to install. Read a few different things but nothing that seems to fit this scenario.

Few pictures at what I am looking at are attached. Not sure weather to go over the lip with the concrete backer board or fill the gap somehow as I need something to hold the tile. Thanks for your help![![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o24qZ.jpg[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have drywall attached to the studs above where the tub is attached.

You should remove the drywall entirely. Then put concrete board or something like densglass or kerdiboard and bring it butted to the tub.

Then your wall sheet and the tub ledge should be nearly flush. Finally, install the tile covering both the wallboard and the tub lip.

Comment: Thanks Mathew I updated the photo is that more like it? I will be using the concrete board for sure.

Comment: I prefer to use the denshield as it comes with a waterproof membrane already on it and it will match up with the drywall next-door. I. E. It is half inch thick which should match your bathroom drywall that is Half inch thick , So no funky transitions

Comment: shouldn't have any drywall around that if you're going to tile the wall. Matthew pretty much said it all. Just one thing to add, after installed the cement board use a waterproofing paint over it before installing the tile.

Answer (score 1):

With such small tiles, you will want to bond those completely to a backer board. So, your options would be as follows:

- Shim out the studs so that you can install a backer board down to an
  1/8 inch above the tub rim. They make drywall shims that are commonly
  available at hardware stores for this purpose.

  You might be able to use a foam backer board, such as Wedi, Kerdi, or
  others, and "route out" the foam backing around the bottom of the
  board so that it will slide over the tub flange and sit 1/8 inch
  above the tub.